# Using pyftpdlib with file conveyor

Tags: python, ftp

I decided to try using [fileconveyor](http://fileconveyor.org) in order to write a simple app that will be able to sync a directory (with very small word files) across all my computers.

In order to do that I also installed [pydtpdlib](https://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib) so as to write a simple ftp server that fileconveyor will link to.

pydtpdlib comes with a number of examples so I used one of them to run a server on 0.0.0.0:2121 and configured file conveyor to connect to it which it did, reporting back that it is

```
- Fully up and running now.
```

The ftp server also logged the connection as such

```
USER 'user' logged in.
FTP session closed (disconnect).
```

But I am not quite sure on what to do now.

1.How can I make the ftp server save uploaded files to a directory of my choosing?

2.Will fileconveyor be able to sync the files both ways?

3.If yes how is that possible, as it would have to track changes on the files in the remote machine?

4.Is what I am trying to do a good idea or should I be using file conveyor differently, possibly not with pyftpdlib but some other service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Answer to 1`: You can configure a directory per user and per anonymus user, see [example](https://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/source/browse/trunk/demo/basic_ftpd.py) (add_user/add_anonymous)

`Answers to pp 2 and 3`: I don't think it's possible to make a reliable implementation of a two-way sync application using only a standard FTP server on the one of the sides. Such apps need more information than FTP protocol provides.

`Answer to 4`: Why do you need pyftpdlib? I believe it's good for building a customized embedded FTP server. You can use any popular FTP servers like [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/) or [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/). They are well documented and you can find a lot of HOW-TOs.
BTW why don't you want to use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)?

Comment: I do use Dropbox, but I am starting getting into python and there are so many amazing modules and I want to experiment with as many as I can. There is one point you didn't answer though, I could not find in the documentation how am I to define the location that I want to use as my servers shared folder. Or is it automatically the location from which the server is being run?

Comment: I added how to configure the location of a user's home directory. BTW I tried to use pydtpdlib to implement an embedded FTP server but finally I switched to Apache FTP server http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/ . It's easer to customize and it has a much better performance in my use case (probably because Java doesn't have things like Python GIL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock)

Comment: That too seems like an interesting project I'll give it a try, thanks for the suggestion.